# Jqueryui Datepicker not displaying calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently using jquery ui `datepicker` for two input fields. In order to call the calendar the inputfield must have a class of `datepicker`. I am using a for loop in the javascript to generate the input fields. I have added the class `datepicker` to each input field that can be possibly generated. But no calendar appears. In the firebug console the html does show that the input fields have class `datepicker`. Now if do this with a static input field it works fine. How can I display calendar when the field is click? [Example](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/courses.php)

In the jquery this is the line where i set the class:

```
content += '</select></br>Class Start Date: <input type="text" id="start_date_'+i+'" name="start_date_'+i+'" class="datepicker" />Class End Date: <input type="text" id="end_date_'+i+'" name="end_date_'+i+'" class="datepicker" /><div>';
```

Full Jquery code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').change(function() {
            var option = $(this).val();
            showFields(option);
            return false;
        });

        function showFields(option) { 
            var content = '';
            for (var i = 1; i <= option; i++) {
                content += '<div id="course_'+i+'"><label>Course # '+i+'</label><br /><label>Course Name:</label> <select id="coursename_'+i+'" name="coursename_'+i+'"><option value="">--- Select ---</option>"'
                    <?php
                        $course_query = $db_con->prepare("SELECT course_id, course_name FROM courses_selection_list ");
                        $course_query->execute();
                        $data = $course_query->fetchAll();
                        foreach ($data as $row) {
                            //dropdown values pulled from database
                            echo 'content += \'<option value="' . $row['course_id'] . ':'.$row['course_name'].'">' . $row['course_name'] . '</option>\';';
                        }
                    ?>
                '"';                   

                content += '</select></br>Class Start Date: <input type="text" id="start_date_'+i+'" name="start_date_'+i+'" class="datepicker" />Class End Date: <input type="text" id="end_date_'+i+'" name="end_date_'+i+'" class="datepicker" /><div>';

            }

            $('#course_catalog').html(content);
        }
    });

    $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val();
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form action="courses.php" method="POST">
    <b>Select the course</b>
    Academy<input id="academy_id" name="acad_id" placeholder="Academy ID" type="text" />
    Courses being offered?
    <select name="courses_offered">
        <option value="default">---Select---</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <div id="course_catalog"></div>
    Static input: <input type="text" id="last_contacted_date" name="last_contacted_date" class="datepicker" />
    <input value="SAVE" name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you forget to include jQuery UI?

Comment: @j08691 Yes it is added

Comment: And initialize a datepicker. It doesn't appear automagically !

Comment: Really? I don't see it on the page you linked to. Nevermind, you just added it.

Comment: `$('.datepicker').datepicker();`

Comment: @j08691 it is added now. Observe how it appears in the static input and not the jquery generated input.

Comment: @adeneo It is initialized. Please as mentioned above observe how it appears in the static input and not the jquery generated input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is make sure that the `datepicker` code runs after the content has been created and added to the DOM.  The easiest way to do this would be to move the `datepicker` code inside your `showFields` method, right at the end.  Like this:

```
function showFields(option) { 

    . . . rest of method . . .

    $('#course_catalog').html(content);

    $('#course_catalog').find(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
}
```

The `$('#course_catalog').find(".datepicker")` part will make sure that only the dynamically added `datepicker` fields will be initialized (you don't want to run it again against the static ones).

Answer (score 1):

Include jQuery UI to your page.

http://jqueryui.com/download/

In the `<head>`:

```
<script type=text/javascript src="your_jquery_ui.js"></script>
```

Ok, you included the jQuery UI, now check your class is not `hasDatepicker` instead of `datepicker` ?

As you see here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

Since you're adding inputs (datepickers) dynamically, the easiest solution is to add this:

```
$('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/C4Et9/)**

BTW, you really only need one document ready call in your page.

Comment: very slick! Just curious, would this create any issues when a `.datepicker` is focused on multiple times? Is there a way to check if `this` datepicker has already been created? Does it even matter?

Comment: I don't think you'd run into any issues, although you could always destroy the datepicker after it's closed.